# Kак проверить значение JSON в тесте PHPUnit?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

```
<?php     
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Check_Json_Value extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public  $client;
    public $nara;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_url' => 'http://fambox2',
            'defaults' => ['exceptions' => false]
        ]);

        $response = $this->client->get('/eng/api/films/separator/poker-am/');
        $data = $response->json();
        $json =json_encode($data) ;
        $json_to_array = json_decode($json);

        var_dump($json_to_array);
    }

    public function test_Delete_Error()
    {
        $response = $this->client->delete('/eng/api/menus/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }

    public function testassertArrayHasKey()
    {

        $response = $this->client->get('/eng/api/films/separator/poker-am/');
        $data = $response->json();
        $json =json_encode($data) ;
        $json_to_array = json_decode($json);

        $this->assertArrayHasKey("video_link", $json_to_array); 
        $this->assertArrayHasKey("watch_later", $json_to_array); 
        $this->assertArrayHasKey("content", $json_to_array); 

        $this->assertEquals('5_FP.mp4', $json_to_array['video_link']);
        $this->assertEquals('false', $json_to_array['watch_later']);
        $this->assertEquals('', $json_to_array['content']);

     }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен JSONPath, в Codeception уже есть имплементация всего необходимого.

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так:

```
$response = $this->call('post', 'api/v1/category');
$this->assertResponseStatus(400);
$response = $response->original;
$json = json_decode($response, true);
$this->assertEquals(400, $json['status']);
```

Comment: Окей, в декодированном массиве нет элемента "статус" или он вообще null. Как тест об этом скажет?

Comment: Очевидно, что вернёт ошибку не соответствия текущего с ожидаемым.

Comment: Это-то я знаю, а как он скажет, что именно сломалось?

Comment: В случае, если индекса не существует, он вернёт: `Undefined index: _status`. В случае, если значение, например, null: `Failed asserting that null matches expected 400.
Expected :400
Actual   :null`

Comment: Угу. И где здесь сообщение о том, что именно в алгоритме сломалось? А если там будет десятикратная вложенность?